Is there a way by which PCIe devices can tell the host/OS that they support D3 power management state or not
Does ACPI have a method by which individual devices like PCIe devices etc can let the BIOS/OS know that it does or does not support D3 state (or any low power state for that matter)?
Tried searching information about the same but could not find any relevant information.

PCIe D3hot support is listed in the capabilities of the respective brigdes and device itself. ACPI is only helpful for D3cold. That said, what are you exactly asking about?

D3 (both cold and hot) states are mandatory and will be implemented in every PCIe device, D1 and D2 are optional and you can check if they are supported by looking into the device's configuration space, in particular, the power management capability structure has a flag to indicate it.
